# Twitter Direct Message Event API 1.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twitter

How to get twitter direct Message with Latest API using C#.net, Earlier I am using LinqToTwitter but after the retirement to DM api Now it fails and I am not found another client in c# who can featch Twitter Data. Is anybody know about how to consume latest API?

```
enter code here
```

static async Task ShowReceivedDMsAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
        {

```
        var dmResponse =
            await
                (from dm in twitterCtx.DirectMessage
                 where dm.Type == DirectMessageType.Show
                 select dm)
                .ToListAsync();

        if (dmResponse != null)
            dmResponse.ForEach(dm =>
            {
                var d = dm.FullText;                   

            });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please could you show us some of the code that you've written? That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: static async Task ShowReceivedDMsAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
        {
            
            var dmResponse =
                await
                    (from dm in twitterCtx.DirectMessage
                     where dm.Type == DirectMessageType.Show
                     select dm)
                    .ToListAsync();

            if (dmResponse != null)
                dmResponse.ForEach(dm =>
                {
                    var d = dm.FullText;                   

                });
        }